# external hive metastore issue in EMR cluster

Tags: hive, emr, metastore

I am pointing my EMR cluster's hive metastore to exteral MySQL RDS instance.
I have created new hive database "mydb" and I got the entry in external MySQL DB in hive.DBS table.

hdfs://ip-10-239-1-118.ec2.internal:8020/user/hive/warehouse/mydb.db    mydb    hadoop  USER

I have also created new hive table "mytable" under mydb database. I got the entry in external MySQL DB in hive.TBLS. so far everything is good..

I terminated my cluster..When I come back next day..I launched new cluster
now, I did the below,
USE MYDB;
create table mytable_2(id int);
I am getting below error,

Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException No Route to Host from  ip-10-239-1-4.ec2.internal/10.239.1.4 to ip-10-239-1-118.ec2.internal:8020 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/NoRouteToHost)

note : 
    IP 10.239.1.4 is my current cluster's name node.
    IP 10.239.1.118 is my earlier cluster's name node

please let me know what properties need to override to avoid this kind of errors?

Answer (score 6):

I have same issue, and fixed.  ^_^

```
hive> create table sales.t1(i int);
```

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.  MetaException(message:Got
> exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException
>
> No Route to Host from  ip-123-234-101-101.ec2.internal/123-234-101-101
> to  ip-111-111-202-202.ec2.internal:8020  failed on socket timeout
> exception:  java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host;
>
> For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/NoRouteToHost)

Cause:

We had an external Metastore for the cluster so that we could get rid of the cluster and spin up a new one anytime.  Hive Metastore still keeps references to old cluster if there are ‘MANAGED’ tables.

Solution:

hive --service metatool -listFSRoot

hive --service metatool -updateLocation < new_value > < old_value >

E.g.:

new_value = hdfs://ip-XXX.New.XXX.XXX:PORT/user/hive/warehouse
old_value = hdfs://ip-YYY.Old.YYY.YYY:PORT/user/hive/warehouse

Comment: Reference: http://www.confusedcoders.com/bigdata/hive/spark-sql-java-net-noroutetohostexception-on-cluster-reboot

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can go into Glue in the AWS console, go to databases/default and edit the entry to have the updated ip in the Location field (which is the output of `hive --service metatool -listFSRoot` )